# BL Speakers connection on dual boot

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bluetooth, dualboot

I have a dual boot Ubuntu and Win10.

I'm using a usb BL antenna for BL on my PC. I use his primarily to connect to a BL speaker.

When I first connected the BL speaker it worked fine on both Ubuntu and Win10. But on all other log-ins it only works on one OS.

So let say it works on Win10. I boot to Win10 and the connection is made automatically.
If I boot into Ubuntu the device is present in the BL device list but is listed as disconnected. If I try to connect it will display "connected" for a brief period of time, and then it will disconnect.
I need to forget the device, discover it, connect to it and it will work.

So now the BL connection is automatically made in Ubuntu, but I have the same problem on Win10.
The device is again displayed in the device list, but I need to forget it and reconnect it to get it to work. Then if I want to use it on Ubuntu I have to do it again.

The BL Speaker in question is SRS XB 10. I'm not sure if its due to the speaker (it is a bit older) or something else.

I could write a startup script for each OS, but would like some "proper" solution if it is available.

Comment: That's how Bluetooth audio devices typically behave, unfortunately. There are exceptions and random automatic connection when we change source devices for the same output but typically happens just like you describe. So, live with it.